# How to pass specific list element to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my web page, I have a list of images. Currently, when the user hovers their mouse over any image for 3 seconds, a `showUpdateImageDialog()` method executes which causes a jQuery dialog to pop up. If the user moves their mouse away from the image at any point during the 3 seconds, the timer is reset and the jQuery dialog never displays:

HTML:

```
<ul class="imageGroup">
    <li class="imageLi">
        <img class="image" src="fizz/buzz/blah.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="imageLi">
        <img class="image" src="fizz/buzz/example.jpg"/>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

<div id="edit-image-description-frame" title="Update Image Description">
    <div id="thumbnail-dialog-image-container">

        <!-- How do I get the 'src' attribute to be the correct image file? -->
        <img src="???"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".imageLi").live({
    mouseenter:
        function()
        {
            window.myTimeout = setTimeout(showUpdateImageDialog,3000);
        },
    mouseleave:
        function()
        {
            clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
        }
});

function showUpdateImageDialog()
{
    $('#edit-image-description-frame').dialog({
        modal:true,
        minHeight:500,
        minWidhth:500
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, this code behaves the same **regardless** of which image in the list the user is hovering over. I need a way for the jQuery dialog to display the specific image that the user is hovering over:

**How can I pass the image's source to jQuery so that I can have the dialog present this image back to the user?** This may seem strange, but the dialog will allow the user to edit metadata about the image and update that metadata. Because of other constraints, I need to use the image's `src` attribute to look up the metadata. Thanks in advance!

Comment: .live() is deprecated. You should use .on().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".imageLi").live({
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        var src = $(this).children('img')[0].src;
        window.myTimeout = setTimeout(function ()
        {
            showUpdateImageDialog(src);
        },3000);
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
    }
});

function showUpdateImageDialog(src)
{
    $('#thumbnail-dialog-image-container').children('img')[0].src = src;

    $('#edit-image-description-frame').dialog({
        modal:true,
        minHeight:500,
        minWidth:500
    });
}
```

Comment: You might want to think about using an existing lightbox plugin, at this point.

Comment: What I was going for but you were faster :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm confused as to why you are indexing the element's children (`[0]`) - wouldn't your code sample only work for the first image in the list? I need this functionality for *any* list element! Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon because you're selecting the `<li>` elements, and each `<li>` only has one `<img>` ...right?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a parameter to your function

```
$(".imageLi").live({
    mouseenter:
        function()
        {
            var element = $(this).find('img');
            window.myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){showUpdateImageDialog(element);},3000);
        },
    mouseleave:
        function()
        {
            clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
        }
});

function showUpdateImageDialog(image)
{
   // do what you want with image variable
   // it refers to the img element inside the li that was hovered
    $('#edit-image-description-frame').dialog({
        modal:true,
        minHeight:500,
        minWidhth:500
    });
}
```